# Looking for open source web project planning software

Tags: web-apps, web-browser, project-management

I am looking for open source project planning software. The type of software I am looking for is like Microsoft Project. Another one that can do similar is OnlyOffice. Both are ok, but also have their limits. While Microsoft Project only exists for Windows but not Linux and only runs locally, OnlyOffice is a bit limited in functionality, not being able to properly handle human resources, working hours, hourly rates at different times, ...

Is there any open source project planning suite running in the browser? A bit like OnlyOffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [OpenAtrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium) (Drupal) is something for you. It does not win a design award, but comes with many features. A long time ago I set up a simple task management and time recording system for a customer. This has been stable for years now.

You might as well check out Redmine.

Otherwise I'm a big basecamp fan, but that's not free.

Comment: Seems Redmine is worth a check. Not sure though, whether it really can do more than OnlyOffice's project planning. You're right about OpenAtrium not winning a design award. Really doesn't. And as for basecam, it doesn't seem to have a Gantt diagram, which I think is an absolute necessity. It though has some features of Kanban as it seems.